# IntelliSense: Completion of words in current document?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a plugin/option that allows intellisense to auto complete words that exists in the document/solution that's currently opened in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your solution with a main project and another secondary project on it.
You should reference the secondary project in the main project and then Visual Studio should get automatically all public Classes, Functions and Methods.

If you still don't get it you can always make an intellisense help file using sandCastle Help File Builder:
For Sandcastle you can go to the [FAQ](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/1aea789d-b226-4b39-b534-4c97c256fac8.htm) and search for more info.

You can also use intellisense in javascript if you attach a -vsdoc.js file. See [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx)

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't what I was looking for - but thanks nontheless! I was looking for intellisense for words in comments and strings, and for integers etc. as well!

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point.
Try pressing ctrl + space. That forces the Intellisense.

Could you attach a screen shot?

Comment: If I have the word "doohickey" written somewhere (comment, method name, class name - anywhere!) inside any file that is currently open inside VS I wish it to appear inside the IntelliSense when triggered by ctrl+space. Think of it as a list of keywords that should be be accessible from the IntelliSense?

Answer (score 0):

I think IntelliSense should do this, try saving and compiling the file first to see if it happens then. If not, you will either need an extension that is capable do that on-the-fly or check out with a trial version of Visual Studio 2010 if it happens there.